# Swift opencv Compile Error 'list' file not found

Tags: ios, swift

Many people provide the solution in Objective-c by renaming .m to .mm.
But how to solve it in Swift?

Answer (score 2):

I ran across this problem recently converting an Obj-C program to a hybrid one with Swift / Obj-C.     I was fully aware of the 'm' / 'mm' issue so that wasn't my problem.

What caused this issue for me was that I had put an include file in the 'bridging' header that referred to OpenCV - both the the #include file and some definitions.    Whoops.

Answer: Check to see if your bridging #include file somehow references opencv - remove.

Comment: I believe this is my issue too. If this is the case how do you pass an Object processed by OpenCV back to swift without causing this clash?

Answer (score 0):

In my case, the problem was the import line in prefix header file. After removing this import, my problem solved[image]

Answer (score 0):

I ran into this problem while working with opencvframework. I fixed this issue by adding #import opencv2/opencv.hpp in objective c .h files. 
This might be help you!