# in xcode project using .a files with swift erorr 'map' file not found

Tags: ios, xcode, swift, .a

I'm trying to add an SDK to my Xcode project. The SDK contains .a files and (headers) .h files. The headers are imported to my Bridging-Header file (successfully).

In the headers there is an `#include <map>`

When I run the project I get an

> Erorr 'map' file not found

When I cmd+click on it Xcode take me to **The LLVM Compiler Infrastructure**.

What is going wrong here?

I'm using Xcode Version 7.2 (7C68) with Swift 2.0.

Comment: Hey  were you able to resolve this ?

Comment: I also have the same issue, did you solve this?

Answer (score 1):

Perhaps you're including C++ files? If so you should add a .mm extension to your implementation instead of .m.

Since you're using Swift you probably need to wrap the component in a Objective-C++ wrapper before you can use it in your project.

Answer (score 0):

I had a exact same problem. However, I solved this problem by removing `#include` from Bridging-Header file.
I'm not an expert on C language family, but according to this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/30457427/1010443), the header file seems to be already included before you include it on Bridging-Header file. In fact, Bridging-Header is only **bridging** Swift-Objective C, it's not relevant to Objective-C compile layer.

Answer (score 0):

If you have any static libraries that depend on libstdc++.tbd you can try what i did.

Not sure if this is the case for you also, but i faced same error and after lot of research i fix it by:

```
Set CLANG_CXX_LIBRARY in build setting to ("C++ Standard Library") libc++ **OR** Compiler default
```

[image]

Actually Both work in my case.
Hope it help someone.

Cheers!!!